# Python json.dumps(<val>) to output minified json?

Tags: python, json, minify

Is there any way to have python's `json.dumps(<val>)` output in minified form? (i.e. get rid of extraneous spaces around commas, colons etc.)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You should set the `separators` parameter:

```
>>> json.dumps([1, 2, 3, {'4': 5, '6': 7}], separators=(',', ':'))
'[1,2,3,{"4":5,"6":7}]'
```

From the docs:

> If specified, separators should be an `(item_separator, key_separator)` tuple. The default is `(', ', ': ')` if indent is `None` and `(',', ': ')` otherwise. To get the most compact JSON representation, you should specify `(',', ':')` to eliminate whitespace.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: just a note, if anyone is still getting newlines try removing the indent argument (which I had set to zero)

Comment: test and go by what you are seeing. I can only comment on what I was seeing, but you've waited 5 months so I'm not even sure which codebase I was in without much searching

Answer (score 11):

There's also a [ujson](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson) library that works much faster and minifies the JSON by default.
Its `dumps` equivalent doesn't have the `separators` parameter and it lacks some more features like custom encoders/decoders, but I thought it might be worth to mention it here.

```
>>> ujson.dumps([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}])
'[1,2,3,{"4":5,"6":7}]'
```