# Remove whitespaces, newlines and tabs in json not in json descriptions

Tags: python, json, powershell, removing-whitespace

I have a json file:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "productGroup": "-1",
      "proofIncome": "-1",
      "docSignType": "-1",
      "creditSumm": "StatusConfirmAmount",
      "message": "Abbreviated verification parameters"
    },
    {
      "productGroup": "-1",
      "proofIncome": "-1",
      "docSignType": "-1",
      "creditSumm": "AdditionalDocumentAmount",
      "message": "Abbreviated validation parameters.\r\n\r\n You need to check the 2nd document\r\n 1 page of the contract is enough"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I remove whitespaces, newlines and tabs in json, but not in json `"message":` descriptions like json formatter - minify/compact:

[image: json formatter]

using Powershell or Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minify JSON with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082289/minify-json-with-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell's `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet has a `-Compress` parameter for this:

```
@'
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "productGroup": "-1",
      "proofIncome": "-1",
      "docSignType": "-1",
      "creditSumm": "StatusConfirmAmount",
      "message": "Abbreviated verification parameters"
    },
    {
      "productGroup": "-1",
      "proofIncome": "-1",
      "docSignType": "-1",
      "creditSumm": "AdditionalDocumentAmount",
      "message": "Abbreviated validation parameters.\r\n\r\n You need to check the 2nd document\r\n 1 page of the contract is enough"
    }
  ]
}
'@ |ConvertFrom-Json |ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Result:

```
{"parameters":[{"productGroup":"-1","proofIncome":"-1","docSignType":"-1","creditSumm":"StatusConfirmAmount","message":"Abbreviated verification parameters"},{"productGroup":"-1","proofIncome":"-1","docSignType":"-1","creditSumm":"AdditionalDocumentAmount","message":"Abbreviated validation parameters.\r\n\r\n You need to check the 2nd document\r\n 1 page of the contract is enough"}]}
```

---

In python you can minify the json by [specifying custom `separators` when calling `json.dumps()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233313/python-json-dumpsval-to-output-minified-json):

```
import json

data = """
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "productGroup": "-1",
      "proofIncome": "-1",
      "docSignType": "-1",
      "creditSumm": "StatusConfirmAmount",
      "message": "Abbreviated verification parameters"
    },
    {
      "productGroup": "-1",
      "proofIncome": "-1",
      "docSignType": "-1",
      "creditSumm": "AdditionalDocumentAmount",
      "message": "Abbreviated validation parameters.\\r\\n\\r\\n You need to check the 2nd document\\r\\n 1 page of the contract is enough"
    }
  ]
}
"""

minified = json.dumps(json.loads(data), separators=(',', ':'))

print(minified)
```

Result:

```
{"parameters":[{"productGroup":"-1","proofIncome":"-1","docSignType":"-1","creditSumm":"StatusConfirmAmount","message":"Abbreviated verification parameters"},{"productGroup":"-1","proofIncome":"-1","docSignType":"-1","creditSumm":"AdditionalDocumentAmount","message":"Abbreviated validation parameters.\r\n\r\n You need to check the 2nd document\r\n 1 page of the contract is enough"}]}
```